# getting NullPointerException using BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

I am making an simple program to test the bean post processore but getting the NullPointerException. Here is the code i have write

Person Class:

```
public class Person {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void init(){
    System.out.println("Bean Initialize");
}

public void destroy(){
    System.out.println("Bean Destroy");
}
}
```

PostProcessor Class:

```
public class Post implements BeanPostProcessor {

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Before Initialization : " + beanName);
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("After Initialization : " + beanName);
    return null;
}
}
```

Controller CLass:

```
public class Controller {

public static void main(String[] args){
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Person p = (Person)context.getBean("person");
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    context.registerShutdownHook();
}
}
```

Spring.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="person" class="com.data.Person" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="name" value="Spring"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.postprocessor.Post"/>
```

Stack Trakce:

```
After Initialization : person
Apr 27, 2016 10:29:08 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'person' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'person' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.controller.Controller.main(Controller.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 12 more
```

This is all the code i have written can any body tell me what is the mistake i am doing here. I shall be thankful.

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: @shmosel i posted the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Before Initialization : " + beanName);
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("After Initialization : " + beanName);
    return bean;
}
```

### Explanation

> `BeanPostProcessor` is a factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean instances, e.g. checking for marker interfaces or wrapping them with proxies.

So purpose of this interface is to define callback methods that you can implement to provide your own **instantiation logic**, **dependency-resolution logic**, **modify the new beans instances** etc.

As an example you can wrap up your bean in a proxy bean at the time of bean instantiation.

If defined `PostProcessor` methods are called by `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` to get the wrapped bean and you are returning `null` from your `PostProcessor` method which essentially creating the **null pointer exception**.

**FYI** Corresponding codes from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java#AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but in order to function properly, BeanPostProcessor should return bean instance in its methods, not null like you did.